# Use a 'in' statement inside a 'case' expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I use `IN` in my "case expression"?

This is my query where I want count if any match like `mumbai` found then as `mumbai`:

```
 select TYPEOFPRODUCT,
        SUM(CASE(BRANCH) WHEN IN('Mumbai1' OR 'Mumbai2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Mumbai'
        SUM(CASE(BRANCH) WHEN IN('Delhi1' OR 'DelhiMain') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Delhi'
from los_ext  
group by TYPEOFPRODUCT
```

Comment: Use double quotes for identifiers, such as column aliases, e.g. `AS "Mumbai"`. (Single quotes are for string literals.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you just need to comma separate values for `IN` rather than using `OR`, and there are two formats for `CASE` expressions, putting the field with the criteria after `WHEN` is more flexible, so I prefer to use it exclusively:

```
SELECT TYPEOFPRODUCT
      ,SUM( CASE WHEN BRANCH IN('Mumbai1','Mumbai2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mumbai
      ,SUM( CASE WHEN BRANCH IN('Delhi1', 'DelhiMain') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Delhi
FROM los_ext  
GROUP BY TYPEOFPRODUCT
```

Answer (score 0):

Its query select sum of individual branchs

```
select TYPEOFPRODUCT,
SUM(CASE WHEN (BRANCH = 'Mumbai1' OR BRANCH = 'Mumbai2' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Mumbai',
SUM(CASE WHEN (BRANCH = 'Delhi1' OR BRANCH = 'DelhiMain' )  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Delhi'
from los_ext  
group by TYPEOFPRODUCT
```